# How can I disable repair?

Tags: installation, wix, wixsharp

I'm using `WixSharp` for building a `windows service installer`.

I want to disable `repair` option.

using those properties remove the option from the `Control Panel` ONLY.

```
"ARPNOREPAIR" , "ARPNOMODIFY"
```

Is there a way to **disable repair** from the `CMD` and right click on `*.msi->repair`?

Comment: No, it is a built in feature of Windows installer. What is causing the requirement to disable it? Are you seeing values overwritten?

Comment: @ Stein Åsmul, we just don't want to support the repair or support all the way, in the Event Viewer it shows as reconfigure

Comment: Then you shouldn't use MSI.

Comment: Are you overwriting your binaries with new ones as part of deployment testing?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm a developer, not a testser. Thought I don't think so .

Answer (score 1):

No. MSI repair can never be fully disabled.  The best practice is to account for this and design/test accordingly.

If your problem is the username/password is being set back then you can put conditions on the CreateServices to not run during a repair.

Comment: Can't I do some abort to installations that detect as repair? Is there a way in wix to detect it?

Comment: sure but that would be a horrible user experience.  It would still try to do a repair and then come back and say it failed.

Comment: do you think it's better practice to have it disable partially than abort?

Comment: That's what disable repair and it's really not great user friendly.. Thanks to @oleg-shilo   installer.Load += e =>
                {
                    if (e.IsRepairing)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Repair is not supported");
                        e.Result = ActionResult.UserExit;
                    }
                        

                };